# Copying parent and child tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with a Parent(ParentID, ParentData) and Child (ChildID, ParentID, ChildData) table. I need to write a script that will  copy both tables into a new DB but with new ParentID for both tables.

I know I could write something like:

```
INSERT INTO Parent(ParentID, ParentData)
SELECT newid(), ParentData FROM OtherDB.dbo.Parent
```

But how do I keep the children bound with the parent if I do that? Is there another, better way to do this that would allow me to keep them together?

Comment: Why do you need new ids, if the tables are in a different database?

Comment: Because the OtherDB is something of an example DB and each DB being copied to is a multi-tenant DB which may need to copy these values into it multiple times.

Comment: You could use the OUTPUT clause to another table with columns for the new and original ID. That way you have a way to tie the new and old ids together so you can use that as a join when inserting the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a temp table with both new and old IDs that I could reference like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempParent(OldParentID, NewParentID, ParentData)

INSERT INTO #TempParent
SELECT(ParentID, newid(), ParentData)
FROM OtherDB.dbo.Parent

INSERT INTO Parent(ParentID, ParentData)
SELECT(NewParentID, ParentData)
FOM #TempParent

INSERT INTO Child(ParentID, ChildData)
SELECT p.NewParentID, c.ChildData
FROM OtherDB.dbo.Child c
LEFT JOIN #TempParent p ON p.OldParentID = c.ParentID

DROP TABLE #TempParent
```

And that works. I'm sure there's a much more elegant way to do this, though.